# Parse.com run cloud code task at intervals

Tags: parse-platform

How can I run a cloud code task at certain intervals? For example my app goes through an array of email addresses and will send an email to the next one every 5 minutes. I'm not sure if this can be a background job because each user of the app can change the list of emails and the intervals that they are sent at. Any advice on how to approach this problem would be appreciated.